# Typecast cross-platform compatibility

Tags: c++, portability

what I'm trying to do is append a binary integer into a string object. So far I have this:

```
int number = 5;
cppstring.append((char*)&number, 4);
```

It works fine on a x86 system with Windows, but some people are saying its not cross-platform and is unsafe. What is the preferred method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's not portable is that ints are not always 4 bytes.  For instance, the ILP64 data model uses 8-bytes ints.  C99 only requires that ints are at least 2 bytes.  Why do you need to do this, and what is the desired behavior if the size of the int is not 4 bytes?

Comment: The contents of the string object are to be stored in a data file and contain integers to be read by a program.

Comment: Then you probably need to define a fixed size integer for the file format, and use the appropriate type (e.g. int32_t) throughout your program.

Answer (score 1):

It will <strike>*always*</strike> usually work, whatever platform you are on, if by working you simply mean "not crash". **EDIT** I missed the `size` argument of `string::append`, so it can actually crash or yield weird results because of a buffer underflow on platforms where `int`s are not 4 bytes long.

However, you may observe different results based on the integer size and [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the platform your code runs on, which is *bad* if you want to share files created on a platform to another platform running the same program.

It depends on what you expect it to do. Windows (usually) operates on [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little-endian#Little-endian) machines that have 32 bits integers, which means your code will append `05 00 00 00` to your string. However, on [big-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big-endian#Big-endian) machines that also have 32 bits integers, your code will append `00 00 00 05` to the string. Worse, your code could run on platforms that have 16-bit big-endian integers, which would append `00 05`.

Depending on which behavior you want, it might be a good idea to implement a "less magical" way to append the bytes, like a `for` loop that *knows* it wants to append 4 bytes in a little-endian fashion:

```
int number = 5;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    char numberByte = (number >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF;
    cppstring.append(&numberByte, 1);
}
```

This way, you're sure results will be consistent across platforms since the code depends on neither the size of an integer nor the byte order.

Comment: It can quite possibly crash, because the int type is allowed to be 16-bit.